# ReactJS. How to compare two fields with react-jsonschema-form such as password / re-enter password fields

Tags: reactjs, validation, passwords

Hi I'm struggling with react and form validation. I am using this plugin: react-jsonschema-form and I can get it working for various fields but I cannot work out how to compare two password fields to make sure that what the user has entered match each other. I can find a few examples but they do not show the whole working component, only snippets and when I try to apply them they do not work. I need to see a fully working self contained component for me to work out how to apply it in my work.

There is a working example here: https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/ and click on the validation button.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: On the client side I'd just use CSS validation, it's simple and efficient. I found this out after doing it all manually, would have saved me a ton of time. Here's a sandbox I did. It's not the cleanest but maybe can give you a perspective. https://codesandbox.io/s/register-page-ntfh7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Here's the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation